# How to save in a variable the value of the following query? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance

I need to implement two variables for save the data result in a query.

I have he following query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT location AS Location, COUNT(*) AS Trucks FROM Truck GROUP BY location) loc
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS TotalOfCampaings, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN cc.campaing_status = 'Complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CampaingsWithCompleteStatus, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN cc.campaing_status = 'InProcess' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CampaingsWithInProcessStatus
    FROM CampaingControl cc INNER JOIN Truck t ON cc.vin = t.vin 
    WHERE t.location = loc.location
) stat
```

This query shows the next table:

|Location|Trucks|TotalOfCampaings|CampaingsWithCompleteStatus|CampaingsWithInProcessStatus

I need to add a column at the end, in the new column i need to get the percent of campaings with complete status, i tried to do something like this:

Percent = (CampaingsWithCompleteStatus / TotalOfCamapings) * 100

But i dont know how to save the values of the query to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    loc.Location,
    loc.Trunks,
    stat.TotalOfCampaings,
    stat.CampaingsWithCompleteStatus,
    stat.CampaingsWithInProcessStatus,
    (1.0 * stat.CampaingsWithCompleteStatus /stat.TotalOfCampaings) * 100 as [Percent]
FROM 
(SELECT location AS Location, COUNT(*) AS Trucks FROM Truck GROUP BY location) loc
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS TotalOfCampaings, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN cc.campaing_status = 'Complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CampaingsWithCompleteStatus, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN cc.campaing_status = 'InProcess' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CampaingsWithInProcessStatus
    FROM CampaingControl cc INNER JOIN Truck t ON cc.vin = t.vin 
    WHERE t.location = loc.location
) stat
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your help, but when I insert values in the tables the percent column always shows 0.

Comment: I supose the both values are integers, because i used the function SUM, or maybe i need to convert to float? i dont know

Comment: Edited: as they are int the result is int too.  To solve it use trick by multiplying with 1.0